# Finding a generating function for number of existing integers

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

> Let $k$ be a positive integer. $\left \{ a_r \right \} _{r=0}^{\infty}$ is the number of integers  which exist between $0$ and $10^k$ (i.e integers with no more than $k$ digits), such that the sum of their digits is no more than $r$.
>
> Find the generating function for $\left \{ a_r \right \} _{r=0}^{\infty}$.

A very similar question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3485868/combinatorics-generating-functions-sums-of-digits).

It is clear to me that we can define $f(x) = (1+x+x^2+\dots+x^9)^{k}$ and this would be a generating function for the problem "how many integers exist with exactly the sum $r$". Meaning that would be the coefficient of $x^r$.

So using this I believe we can express $a_r$, but the question is to **find a generating function for $a_r$**.

So is this still a good direction, or should I think about the problem differently?

Comment: Markus Scheuer’s answer to the question to which you linked contains the generating function that you want: just remove the initial $[x^r]$ (and the final $+1$, if you don’t want to include $10^k$) from the first blue expression. The reasoning is in the material above the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we denote the number of integers with sum no more than $r$ by $a_r$ and the number of integers with sum exactly $r$ by $b_r$, we have

$$
a_r=\sum_{k=0}^rb_k\;.
$$

You know the generating function for $b_k$. Summing a sequence corresponds to multiplying its generating function by $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac1{1-x}$. Thus the generating function you want is

$$
\frac{\left(1+\cdots+x^9\right)^k}{1-x}=\frac{\left(1-x^{10}\right)^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\;.
$$

Note that this is also an intermediate result that Markus Scheuer arrived at in line $(6)$ in his answer to the question you linked to. He included $10^k$ instead of $0$, but the result is the same.

Comment: I lost you at  "Summing a sequence corresponds to dividing its generating function by...".

Can you explain what you mean by that? this material is pretty new to me

Comment: @paxtibimarce: I added an intermediate step. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: I'm still not sure why summing a sequence is the same as multiplying its generating function by this sum. Is this something trivial or could you tell me where I could read about it maybe?

Comment: @paxtibimarce: You can read more about it in Markus Scheuer's answer in the thread you linked to (the bullet point that starts "sum of digits via $\frac1{1-x}$"). But I suggest that you just write out the multiplication and see for yourself that (and why) the coefficients of the product are the partial sums of the coefficients of the original series.

Comment: I got it, very cool trick :)
Thank you

Comment: Litlle follow-up question if you're interested, how would we find $a_{18}$ using the function we found?

We could look at the original function $F(x)=(1+x+...+x^9)^k (1+x+x^2+...)$ and solve combinatorially by summing.

I was wondering how to reach a more algebraic solution directly from the function you found.

Comment: @paxtibimarce:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left[x^r\right]\frac{\left(1-x^{10}\right)^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}
&=&
\left[x^r\right]\left(\sum_{j=0}^k\binom kj(-1)^jx^{10j}\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom{k+m}kx^m\right)
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac r{10}\right\rfloor}\binom kj(-1)^j\binom{k+r-10j}k\;.
\end{eqnarray}

For $r=18$, this is $\binom{k+18}k-k\binom{k+8}k$.